# Toshiba Satellite touchpad not working correctly in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

I have a P305-S882 Satellite laptop that I have installed Windows 7 on.  I went to the website and downloaded the drivers available for Windows 7, but it still does not work correctly.

The left mouse key does not always work like it should.

I also tried loading the Synaptic Touchpad driver for Vista, but it still does not work correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a hardware problem and once I had the touchpad replaced it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the left mouse key does not always work like it should", what exactly do you mean?

And since you've updated the drivers, have you looked for hardware causes? Could there be something underneath the buttons? I would try cleaning out the area with compressed air.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is hardware.  The left mouse button acts eradically.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4 satellites in my home (family computers) and only the ones **I upgraded to windows7** have the same or similar issues. the one that came with windows 7 works fine

I believe it is a driver issue...but I can't find the proper driver.

one other issue I have is with the scroll function on the touch pad

I have only had one instance of the left click not working...and I finally just re-installed the os...and **that** bug went away